# Comparing letters with enum

Tags: c, arrays, string, enums, char

Trying to do a Caesar cipher.

```
enum alfabeto{
    A=0,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,Z         // 21
};

void cifra(char *string, int k){
    enum alfabeto letter;    // initialize the enum letter
    size_t i = 0;    // initialize counter
    while (*(string+i)!='\0'){    // while string is not ended
        letter = *(string+i);     // attempt to "link" the enum letter to the equivalent (already uppercased) char
        printf("%d", letter);
        letter = (letter+k) % 21;    // then it increases of a factor k and if it goes out of 21, it should take the right value
        printf(" %d\n", letter);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./"cesare" 

write the text:
>TEST

choose the factor k:
>2

84 8
69 14
83 7
84 8
```

The values are wrong... maybe because I can't "link" a enum value to a char... How could I do this?c

Comment: 1) Why not the complete alphabet? 2) Why `*(string+i)` instead of `string[i]`?

Comment: Each input letter is encoded as an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value (e.g. `T` -> `84`), but your output values are limited to the range [0, 21), which do not correspond with the ASCII alphabet.  You need to shift them back over into the correct range; this is typically done by adding a "base" value of `'a'` or `'A'`, depending on the case of the input.

Comment: You need a character lookup char array to match your enums.  No reflections for the enum name in C.  Because the range has breaks, you will also either need to scan that lookup array  O(n) to find the value, or add padding for the missing letters to allow an O(1)  lookup.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan how can I make a lookup table? Never done that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    letter = *(string+i);     // attempt to "link" the enum letter to the equivalent (already uppercased) char
```

Should be:

```
    letter = *(string+i) - 'A';     // attempt to "link" the enum letter to the equivalent (already uppercased) char
```

That way, '`A`' will map to zero, as required.

Comment: His range is not continuous.  He needs to account for missing letter with a lookup table as well.

Comment: If you just put  a "I'm a bad value" in the missing letters, you can still look up the offset, otherwise it's a search through a Pair structure of letter and value.  Not bad, but annoying.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how can I make a lookup table? Never done that.

Answer (score 0):

```
//                         A B C D E F G H I  J  K L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z
const int offsetTable[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,-1,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,-1,-1,-1,20};
const char charLookupTable[] = "ABCDEFGHILMNOPQRSTUVZ";

// Should probably use a struct for the above to prevent size mis-matches
const int offsetTableSize = 21;

void cifra(char *str, int k){
  char letter;
  int newLetterOffset;

  printf("%s\n", str);  // Show initial string.

  while (letter = *str++){    // while string is not ended
    const int oldLetterOffset = offsetTable[letter - 'A']; // Get the old letter's offset.
    if(letter <= 'A'  || letter >= 'Z' || oldLetterOffset == -1)
    {
        printf("\nBad character %c found - ending string processing\n", letter);
        return;
    }
    newLetterOffset = (oldLetterOffset + k) % offsetTableSize; // Get the letter's position, add the global offset, and wrap to table size.
    printf("%c", charLookupTable[newLetterOffset]);  // Use that offset to read the character's value from the shortened alphabet.
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
  cifra("HELLO", 0);
  cifra("HELLO", 1);
  cifra("HELLo", 1);
  cifra("YELLO", 1);

  return 0;
```

}

Notice I needed 2 tables to do the work as we had to go into and out of your shortened character set.  Typically, we would use a struct to hold those 2 arrays, but I kept it simple for this example.  Also, the arrays do not need to be global, but I placed them there also to keep things simpler.

Notice I also changed your printf() values to use characters and strings to make it easier to read.

Finally, I added some error checking as you cannot trust a user to give you a good string.  Many a security flaw or random crash has resulted from that.